# Main Method Not Found - JSON Related

Tags: java, json, methods, program-entry-point

I am following an example given on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_quick_guide.htm

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

class JsonEncodeDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args){
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      obj.put("name", "foo");
      obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
      obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
      obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));

      System.out.print(obj);
   }
}
```

I met the following error:
Error: Main method not found in class JsonEncodeDemo, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

What seems to be the problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: hate to tell you, but your very first issue is: following TutorialsPoint. It's a bunch of tutorials riddled with errors, outdated (and wrong) information. you may want to choose a better book. That being said: did you save the file before compile/run?

Comment: In IDEs like eclipse you may have to define the main-class of your program.

Comment: are you sure you are running the correct class

Comment: is your class file indeed in its package folder?

Comment: And remeber to add the correct jar to your classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you write the code using to compile and run your program?
I guess there might be a typo.